# "ValueError: Unknown optimizer: momentum" correct name for Momentum Optimizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

I am trying to train my program using the Momentum optimizer but when I input "momentum" as the optimizer, it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: Unknown optimizer: momentum
```

The code I am using is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

start_time = time.time()


data = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle Boot']

train_images = train_images/255.0

test_images = test_images/255.0

model = keras.Sequential([
                           keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
                           keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
                           keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer="Ftrl", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

print("Test acc is:", test_acc)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I tried typing momentum in different ways but I can't seem to fix the correct name. What is it?

Comment: Your question is about momentum, but your code uses Ftrl; which optimizer are you trying to use exactly? (And what are your `keras.__version__` and `tf.__version__`?)

Comment: tf has no plain "momentum" optimizer: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/optimizers in TensorFlow Core r2.0, can you provide us the version you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow has no plain "momentum" optimizer: [tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/optimizers](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/optimizers) in TensorFlow.
Though [Tutorialpoints](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tensorflow/tensorflow_quick_guide.htm) references to it.

Nevertheless it has `MomentumOptimizer()` class.

So you should first define a `MomentumOptimizer()` class instance, then you can pass through as parameter to the `compile()` method.

**Note:** `lr`(learning rate) and `m`(momentum) parameters need to be defined by you.

```
momentum = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(lr, m)
model.compile(optimizer=momentum, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Comment: I got another error saying that "self" is not defined.

Comment: @KhosrawAzizi Always provide full error messages, software versions etc., if you want a good answer. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it did...Thanks!